# XAMPP and MySQL workbench

Tags: apache-http-server, php, mysql, webserver, database

Ok so I have this message error in XAMPP:

`20:25:37  [mysql]  Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
20:25:37  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
20:25:37  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
20:25:37  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
20:25:37  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
20:25:37  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
20:25:37  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums`

And this one:

`20:25:34  [mysql]  Problem detected!
20:25:34  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MySQL57"!
20:25:34  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
20:25:34  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
20:25:34  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port`

I have installed XAMPP and MySQL workbench version 6.3.

I've tried changing the port numbers of the MySQL service of XAMPP to see if that will solve the problem but that didn't work.

I also tried replacing the field $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; on the config.inic.php file of XAMPP with my MySQL workbench password but the problem is still in there, I can't start neither the MySQL XAMPP service nor MySQL workbench.

Do you know of anything else I can do to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice. If you have more to add, you can edit your posts.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem.

You have to make sure to use the right password for the workbench. Then if you want to use the PHP my admin tool you have to make some changes in the files of XAMPP.

You will have to search the config.inic.php in the folder PhpMyAdmin and put the password in the line 21 (`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''`). Then you have to change the port number of the connection with XAMPP, for that go to the config mysql button in XAMPP and open de my.ini file and change the 3306 port for another one (33060 for example). Now restart XAMPP and it's done.

That work for me, hope this help you guys!